# MWS Report doesn't update report request status from "_SUBMITTED_"

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

I have been using MWS report API for a few years and today found a weird status that the requested report doesn't change status from "*SUBMITTED*".

I use `_GET_FLAT_FILE_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_BY_LAST_UPDATE_` report type.

Is there anything updated for this report?

Since Amazon MWS support is not really helpful, I am raising a question here.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the issue in several ways, I found that it's due to lots of queued reports. That's why my last requested report was still in "*SUBMITTED*" status.

I think it's due to the recent outage of AWS and lots of report requests were pending.
I cancelled pending requests to process my request faster.

As expected, the status got changed to "*IN_PROGRESS*" soon and voila.